# store query table output in variable

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

How can I store query output in a variable?

I have following query table:

```
|Query:SomeQueryClass|
|ObjId|ObjValue|
|someId|<IWantToStoreThisValue>|
```

I tried following:

```
|Query:SomeQueryClass|
|ObjId|ObjValue|
|someId|$value=|
```

However test fails and I have following output

```
|Query:SomeQueryClass|
|ObjId|ObjValue|
|someId|[realValue] expected [$value=]|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way to solve this problem.

For example `$object` contains data I need to store in a variable

```
!|$object|
|getVariable1?|getVariable2?|
|$var1=|$var2=|
```

and data is stored in `var1` and `var2`